# socket not creating win32 c++

Tags: c++, sockets, winapi

I am creating a socket. It works first time easily then i stop the socket and regenerate it gives me error

```
class MainServer{
private:
    SOCKET soo;
public:
    // I have Basically Created Server Socket in this Function
    // And passed it
    SOCKET socket_control_mob(){
        struct sockaddr_in server;
        WSADATA wsa;

        printf("\nInitialising Winsock...");
        if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa) != 0)
        {
            printf("Failed. Error Code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
            MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Failed"), L"Failed", NULL);
            soo = NULL;
            return soo;
        }

        printf("Initialised.\n");
        //MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Initialised"), L"Simple Message", NULL);
        //Create a socket
        if ((soo = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            printf("Could not create socket : %d", WSAGetLastError());
            MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Socket Not Created1"), L"Failed", NULL);
            soo = NULL;
            return soo;
        }
        printf("Socket created.\n");

        //Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
        server.sin_family = AF_INET;
        server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
        server.sin_port = htons(8890);

        //Bind
        if (bind(soo, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            printf("Bind failed with error code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
            MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Binding Error"), L"Failed", NULL);
            soo = NULL;
            return soo;
        }

        puts("Bind done");
        //MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Bind Done"), L"Simple Message", NULL);

        return soo;
    }
    bool server_close_socket(){
            closesocket(soo);
            WSACleanup();
            return true;
    }
};
```

I have created a socket by calling

```
MainServer s;
s.socket_control_mob()
```

I have stopped socket by

```
s.server_close_socket()
```

Socket does not create after stopping it

Comment: How long are you waiting between runs? And what exactly goes wrong?

Comment: First time socket executes I dont get any error second time I get "Socket Not Created1" message pops up and socket does not create. I stop the socket after 5 seconds and recreate socket then i gets error

Comment: What is the value of `WSAGetLastError()` ?

Comment: I get value of WSAGetLastError() is 6

Comment: Error 6 (`ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE`) is not a WinSock error code. WinSock errors are 10000+. Also, your code is leaking the `SOCKET` if `bind()` fails. Once `socket()` returns a valid socket, you have to call `closesocket()` to free it when you are done using it. You have to close it if `bind()` fails. And `soo = NULL` is just plain wrong, you have to use `soo = INVALID_SOCKET` instead. And `server_close_socket()` should be setting `soo = INVALID_SOCKET` after closing the socket.

Answer (score 0):

You are mishandling the socket, and even the WinSock library itself.  Try something more like this instead:

```
class MainServer
{
private:
    SOCKET soo;
    bool init;

public:
    MainServer()
        : soo(INVALID_SOCKET), init(false)
    {
        WSADATA wsa;

        printf("\nInitialising Winsock...");
        int err = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa);
        if (err != 0)
        {
            printf("Failed. Error Code : %d\n", err);
            MessageBox(NULL, L"WSAStartup Failed", L"Failed", NULL);
        }
        else
        {
            init = true;
            printf("Initialized.\n");
            //MessageBox(NULL, L"Initialized", L"Simple Message", NULL);
        }
    }

    ~MainServer()
    {
        close_server_socket();
        if (init)
            WSACleanup();
    }

    SOCKET socket_control_mob()
    {
        struct sockaddr_in server = {0};

        close_server_socket();

        //Create a socket
        soo = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        if (soo == INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            printf("Could not create socket. Error Code : %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            MessageBox(NULL, L"Socket Not Created", L"socket Failed", NULL);
            return INVALID_SOCKET;
        }
        printf("Socket created.\n");

        //Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
        server.sin_family = AF_INET;
        server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
        server.sin_port = htons(8890);

        //Bind
        if (bind(soo, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            printf("Bind failed. Error Code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
            MessageBox(NULL, L"Binding Error", L"bind Failed", NULL);
            close_server_socket();
            return INVALID_SOCKET;
        }
        printf("Bind done.\n");
        //MessageBox(NULL, L"Bind Done", L"Simple Message", NULL);

        return soo;
    }

    void server_close_socket()
    {
        if (soo != INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            closesocket(soo);
            soo = INVALID_SOCKET;
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a well-known thing. Your created socket is in FIN_WAIT state. To avoid the problem, wait for 2 minutes before re-running the program, follow 'graceful shutdown' protocol or provide SO_REUSEADDR option for the socket.

Comment: @ElderBug OP indeed did. However, seen that issue surfaced millions of times, I have a reasonal suspicion that OP misunderstood the isssue. Wanna bet, say, 50 of reputation?

Comment: OP said he get "Socket Not Created1". If you read his code, this error is printed when `socket()` fails, not `bind()`. Binding is after that, and doesn't print the same thing.

Comment: If i wait for 2 minutes then I dont get any error but I am not able to send request from client